# What is the best way to add space between my UIButtons in a UIStackView

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistackview

I have a calculator app and I'm trying to add an inset to the buttons. I don't want to increase the space between the UIStackView items because that would make my button area bigger, which is not what I want. Instead - I want to make my buttons smaller. I have tried using `button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)`but that does nothing?

The buttons **ONLY** have *aspect 1:1 constraint* applied to them, and both the horizontal and vertical UIStackViews' *Distribution* is set to ***Fill Equally*** - Their width and heigh is never set and is determined by other elements on the screen, which is why I find it difficult to make them smaller programmatically in Swift.

[image: Plusee Calculator App)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIStackView`s will fill an subview regardless to the frame, inset you set it. What you can do is embed each `UIButton` in a `UIView`, and add some constraints to give some padding.

Comment: It feels like a bit of a long way around but it works, TY!